# websockets transfers in raspberry is very slow

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, websocket, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to locally move data between multiple client (processes) by transferring and routing them through a single server process. This transfer is over websockets on localhost:8080. Both server and clients are implemented in python; the client being a simple version of websocket-client library of python, and the server is a tornado.web.Application object.
Now, when transferring packets (about 20 - 100bytes in size ) from client 1 -> server -> client2, I see different speeds in different platforms:
1. Amazon AWS : gives me a time delay of about 0.7msec.
2. Raspberry Pi : gives me a time delay of 4.5msec.

Should the clients employ any sort of queuing (collections.deque library) on top, the delay aggrevates to sometimes over 100msec in RPi, although in AWS it stays within 7.5msec.
I understand that local IP address sockets have to be maintained in volatile memory as file descriptors, and adding the networking overhead of different headers and websocket related parameters, increases the latency during packet processing by a lot. 
My suspicion here is that the RAM read-write speeds on RPi is way lesser than AWS. I confirmed this by running a 'dd' on each platform to transfer blocks of 1k size. The RPi doesnt go beyond 95Mb/sec while the AWS easily goes beyond 900 Mb/sec. The RPi connects to the SD card via a serial interface, I think. But Amazon must be doing much better than that with their EC2 VMs.

My question here is whether this suspicion is true ? Is it the RAM access speeds that could be solely responsible for this performance difference between the 2 platforms.

Note : I am sorry, but I do not want to paste parts of my code here unless there is a dire reason/need for it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I rather doubt folks can answer such a theoretical question without seeing relevant code.  The Raspberry PI is massively less powerful hardware than an AWS server at all levels of your transfer.  Likely, you are seeing an accumulation of a whole bunch of parts of the chain that are slower on the Raspberry Pi.  95Mbps sounds suspiciously like a common access speed for an ordinary SD card too (though you can buy faster cards if the controller can go faster).

Answer (score 0):

After quite some research, I was able to find out some details which are contributing to these delays:

1. The transfer of messages (client -> server or server -> client) were websocket transfers. Hence, one needs to add in the whole IP stack on top of each packet. This packet was stored in the Raspberry's memory (which has much lower read/write speeds than compared to AWS VMs).

   - Running a simple 'dd' command on both machines shows the difference.
   - The effect can be made more visible by increasing the payload of the packet (triggering network fragmentation) and turning off Nagle's Algorithm for TCP in 'setsockopt' (TCP_SETNODELAY).
2. I saw similar delays if I shifted to synchronous message transfers between threads of different processes and compared them on AWS and Raspberry.

Example:

```
Write speed on AWS:
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1048576 count=200
200+0 records in
200+0 records out
209715200 bytes (210 MB, 200 MiB) copied, 0.301986 s, 694 MB/s

Write speed on Raspberry:
# dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1048576 count=200
200+0 records in
200+0 records out
209715200 bytes (210 MB) copied, 23.9886 s, 8.7 MB/s
```